# Undefined reference to error clase::clase() - C++

Tags: c++, clase

quisiera saber porque me salta este tipo de error en la sección que corresponde a Juego::Juego. No logro encontrar el problema. Habia tenido problemas con la parte de Setlimit en Juego también  y ahora las distintas clases de  "Auto" están funcionando correctamente en cada de sus clases, pero no entiendo porque en esta parte me esta dando problemas.Puede ser que hice algún error en algún constructor o lo implemente mal. Con esto del tema clases soy bastante nuevo así que tal vez se me este pasando algo teórico y simple pero al ser un trabajo grande para mi (es la primera vez que trabajo en un código de este tamaño) puede estar ocasionandome un problema mayor al que realmente es.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    HANDLE hConsole;
    COORD cursorLoc;
    std::cout.flush();
    cursorLoc.X = x;
    cursorLoc.Y = y;
    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, cursorLoc);
}

void textcolor(int ForgC)
{
    WORD wColor;
    
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    
    
    if(GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi))
    {
        wColor = (csbi.wAttributes & 0xF0) + (ForgC & 0x0F);
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, wColor);
    }
    return;
}


    
class Auto {
protected:
    int matriz[5][4];
    int color[5][4]; 
    int ancho,alto,pasoX,pasoY,xnueva,ynueva,maxLimitX,maxLimitY,minLimitX,minLimitY,x,y,velocidad;
    
    clock_t tempo; 
    clock_t paso; 
    
    
    
public:
    void dibujar();
    void borrar(); 
    Auto(int v, int x0,int y0);
    void setLimit(int, int,int, int);
    Auto(int vel);
    bool update();
    int gettempo();
    int getX();
    int getY();
};

Auto::Auto(int vel, int x0,int y0) {
    velocidad = vel;
    paso=CLOCKS_PER_SEC/velocidad;
    tempo=clock(); 
    
    
    
    int Color = (rand()%15)+1;
    
    
    matriz[0][0]=0;  color[0][0] = 8;
    matriz[0][1]=219; color[0][1] = 15;
    matriz[0][2]=0; color[0][2] = 8;
    matriz[0][3]=219; color[0][3] = 15;
    matriz[1][0]=0;  color[1][0] = Color;
    matriz[1][1]=61; color[1][1] = 8;
    matriz[1][2]=47; color[1][2] = Color;
    matriz[1][3]=61; color[1][3] = 8;
    matriz[2][0]=30; color[2][0] = Color;
    matriz[2][1]=61; color[2][1] = 8;
    matriz[2][2]=0;  color[2][2] = Color;
    matriz[2][3]=61; color[2][3] = 8;
    matriz[3][0]=0;  color[3][0] = Color;
    matriz[3][1]=61; color[3][1] = 8;
    matriz[3][2]=92; color[3][2] = Color;
    matriz[3][3]=61; color[3][3] = 8;
    matriz[4][0]=0;  color[4][0] = 8;
    matriz[4][1]=219; color[4][1] = 15;
    matriz[4][2]=0; color[4][2] = 8;
    matriz[4][3]=219; color[4][3] = 15;
    
    ancho = 5;
    alto = 4;
    pasoX = 3;
    pasoY = 3;
    x = x0;
    y = y0;
    xnueva = x0;
    ynueva = y0;
    
    
    dibujar();
    
}
int Auto::getX()
{
    return x;
}
int Auto::getY()
{
    return y;
}
int Auto::gettempo()
{
    return tempo;
}


void Auto::dibujar()
{
    
    for (int i= 0; i<ancho; i++)
    {
        for (int k= 0; k<alto; k++)
        {
            textcolor(color[i][k]);
            gotoxy(x+i,y+k);
            cout<<(char) matriz[i][k];
        }
    }
}

void Auto::borrar()
{
    
    for (int i= 0; i<ancho+1; i++)
    {
        for (int k= 0; k<alto+1; k++)
        {
            textcolor(color[i][k]); 
            gotoxy(x+i,y+k);
            cout<<" ";
        }
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Auto1: public Auto {
    
public:
    
    Auto1(int v, int x0,int y0);
    Auto1();
    void setLimit(int x0, int x1,int y0, int y1);
    bool update();
};

bool Auto1::update()
{
    
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        int tecla = getch();
        bool moves = false;
        
        switch(tecla){
        case (72): {
            if (y - alto > minLimitY )
            {
                borrar(); y = y - pasoY; moves = true;
            } break;
        }
        case (80):{ 
            if (y < maxLimitY)
            {
                borrar(); y = y + pasoY; moves = true;
            } break;
        }
        case (77):{ 
            if (x + ancho < maxLimitX)
            {
                borrar(); x = x + pasoX; moves = true;
            } break;
        }
        case (75):
        { 
            if (x - ancho > minLimitX)
            {
                borrar(); x = x - pasoX; moves = true;
            } break;
        }
        
        
        if(moves) 
        {
            dibujar();
        }
        }   
        
    return true;    
    }
    return false;
}


void Auto1::setLimit(int x0, int x1,int y0, int y1){
    maxLimitX = x1;
    maxLimitY = y1;
    minLimitX = x0;
    minLimitY = y0;
    
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Auto2: public Auto {
protected:
    
    bool cambio;
    int colorAuto;
    
    
public:
    
    Auto2(int v, int x0,int y0);
    Auto2();
    void Cambio();
    void update();
};

Auto2:: Auto2(int v, int x0,int y0): Auto( v, x0, y0){
    
    cambio = true;
    colorAuto = 10;
    
    
    matriz[0][0]=0;  color[0][0] = 8;
    matriz[0][1]=219; color[0][1] = 15;
    matriz[0][2]=0; color[0][2] = 8;
    matriz[0][3]=219; color[0][3] = 15;
    matriz[1][0]=0;  color[1][0] = colorAuto;
    matriz[1][1]=61; color[1][1] = 8;
    matriz[1][2]=47; color[1][2] = colorAuto;
    matriz[1][3]=61; color[1][3] = 8;
    matriz[2][0]=30; color[2][0] = colorAuto;
    matriz[2][1]=61; color[2][1] = 8;
    matriz[2][2]=0;  color[2][2] = colorAuto;
    matriz[2][3]=61; color[2][3] = 8;
    matriz[3][0]=0;  color[3][0] = colorAuto;
    matriz[3][1]=61; color[3][1] = 8;
    matriz[3][2]=92; color[3][2] = colorAuto;
    matriz[3][3]=61; color[3][3] = 8;
    matriz[4][0]=0;  color[4][0] = 8;
    matriz[4][1]=219; color[4][1] = 15;
    matriz[4][2]=0; color[4][2] = 8;
    matriz[4][3]=219; color[4][3] = 15;
    
    dibujar();
    
}

void Auto2::Cambio(){
    
    if (cambio){
        matriz[4][0]=219;  color[4][0] = 15;
        matriz[4][1]=0; color[4][1] = 8;
        matriz[4][2]=219; color[4][2] = 15;
        matriz[4][3]=0; color[4][3] = 8;
        
        matriz[3][0]=61;  color[1][0] = 8;
        matriz[3][1]=47; color[1][1] = colorAuto;
        matriz[3][2]=61; color[1][2] = 8;
        matriz[3][3]=0; color[1][3] = 8;
        
        matriz[2][0]=61; color[2][0] = 8;
        matriz[2][1]=0; color[2][1] = colorAuto;
        matriz[2][2]=61;  color[2][2] = 8;
        matriz[2][3]=31; color[2][3] = colorAuto;
        
        matriz[1][0]=61;  color[3][0] = 8;
        matriz[1][1]=92; color[3][1] = colorAuto;
        matriz[1][2]=61; color[3][2] = 8;
        matriz[1][3]=0; color[3][3] = 8;
        
        matriz[0][0]=219;  color[0][0] = 15;
        matriz[0][1]=0; color[0][1] = 8;
        matriz[0][2]=219; color[0][2] = 15;
        matriz[0][3]=0; color[0][3] = 8;
    }
    else {
        matriz[0][0]=0;  color[0][0] = 8;
        matriz[0][1]=219; color[0][1] = 15;
        matriz[0][2]=0; color[0][2] = 8;
        matriz[0][3]=219; color[0][3] = 15;
        matriz[1][0]=0;  color[1][0] = colorAuto;
        matriz[1][1]=61; color[1][1] = 8;
        matriz[1][2]=47; color[1][2] = colorAuto;
        matriz[1][3]=61; color[1][3] = 8;
        matriz[2][0]=30; color[2][0] = colorAuto;
        matriz[2][1]=61; color[2][1] = 8;
        matriz[2][2]=0;  color[2][2] = colorAuto;
        matriz[2][3]=61; color[2][3] = 8;
        matriz[3][0]=0;  color[3][0] = colorAuto;
        matriz[3][1]=61; color[3][1] = 8;
        matriz[3][2]=92; color[3][2] = colorAuto;
        matriz[3][3]=61; color[3][3] = 8;
        matriz[4][0]=0;  color[4][0] = 8;
        matriz[4][1]=219; color[4][1] = 15;
        matriz[4][2]=0; color[4][2] = 8;
        matriz[4][3]=219; color[4][3] = 15;
        
    }
    
    cambio = !cambio;
    
}

void Auto2::update()
{
    
    if(tempo+paso<clock())
    {
        dibujar();
        tempo=clock(); 
    }
}



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Auto3 : public Auto2 {
    
public:
    
    Auto3(int v, int x0,int y0);
    Auto3();
    void setLimit(int x0, int x1,int y0, int y1);
    void Colorear();
    void update();
    
    
    
};

Auto3::Auto3(int v, int x0,int y0): Auto2( v, x0, y0){
    
    cambio = true;
    colorAuto = (rand()%15)+1;
    
    
    
    matriz[0][0]=0;  color[0][0] = 8;
    matriz[0][1]=219; color[0][1] = 15;
    matriz[0][2]=0; color[0][2] = 8;
    matriz[0][3]=219; color[0][3] = 15;
    matriz[1][0]=0;  color[1][0] = colorAuto;
    matriz[1][1]=61; color[1][1] = 8;
    matriz[1][2]=47; color[1][2] = colorAuto;
    matriz[1][3]=61; color[1][3] = 8;
    matriz[2][0]=30; color[2][0] = colorAuto;
    matriz[2][1]=61; color[2][1] = 8;
    matriz[2][2]=0;  color[2][2] = colorAuto;
    matriz[2][3]=61; color[2][3] = 8;
    matriz[3][0]=0;  color[3][0] = colorAuto;
    matriz[3][1]=61; color[3][1] = 8;
    matriz[3][2]=92; color[3][2] = colorAuto;
    matriz[3][3]=61; color[3][3] = 8;
    matriz[4][0]=0;  color[4][0] = 8;
    matriz[4][1]=219; color[4][1] = 15;
    matriz[4][2]=0; color[4][2] = 8;
    matriz[4][3]=219; color[4][3] = 15;
    
    
    
    
    
}

void Auto3::Colorear(){
    
    colorAuto = (rand()%15)+1;
    
    color[1][0] = colorAuto;
    color[1][2] = colorAuto;
    color[2][0] = colorAuto;
    color[2][2] = colorAuto;
    color[3][0] = colorAuto;
    color[3][2] = colorAuto;
    
}

void Auto3::update(){
    
    if(tempo+paso<clock()){
        dibujar();
        tempo=clock();
    }
}

void Auto3::setLimit(int x0, int x1,int y0, int y1){
    maxLimitX = x1;
    maxLimitY = y1;
    minLimitX = x0;
    minLimitY = y0;
    
}


/********/

class Juego{
    
    int teclas[4];
    Auto1 auto1;
    Auto2 auto2;
    Auto3 auto3;
    int checkCollision();
    
    
public:
    Juego();
    void play();
    
};


Juego::Juego(){
    
    auto1 = Auto1(4,4,4);
    auto1.setLimit(0,130,0,45);
    auto2 = Auto2(10,14,14);
    auto2.setLimit(0,130,0,45);
    auto3 = Auto3(10,30,30);
    auto3.setLimit(0,130,0,45);
}

int Juego::checkCollision(){
    
    int x1 = auto1.getX();
    int y1 = auto1.getY();
    int x2 = auto2.getX();
    int y2 = auto2.getY();
    int x3 = auto3.getX();
    int y3 = auto3.getY();
        
    int ancho = 3;
    int alto = 4;
    
    
        if(x1 > (x2 - ancho) && x1 < (x2 + ancho) && 
           y1 > (y2 - alto) && y1 < (y2 + alto))
        {
            return 2;
        }
           
           if(x1 > (x3 - ancho) && x1 < (x3 + ancho) && 
              y1 > (y3 - alto) && y1 < (y3 + alto))
           {
               return 3;
           }
          
          
          return 0;
}


void Juego::play(){
    
    
    bool flag = true;
    while(flag) {
        
        auto1.update();
        auto2.update();
        auto3.update();
        
        if (checkCollision() == 2){
            auto2.Cambio();
        }
        if (checkCollision() == 3){
            auto3.Colorear();
        }   
        
        if(auto1.gettempo()==0 && auto2.gettempo()==0 && auto3.gettempo()==0)
        {
            cout<<"Ninguno ha ganado. Se termina el juego."<<endl;
            flag=false;
        }
        if(auto1.gettempo()==0 && auto2.gettempo()==0)
        {
            cout<<"El ganador fue el auto3."<<endl;
            flag=false;
        }
        if(auto2.gettempo()==0 && auto3.gettempo()==0)
        {
            cout<<"El ganador fue el auto1."<<endl;
            flag=false;
        }
        if(auto1.gettempo()==0 && auto3.gettempo()==0)
        {
            cout<<"El ganador fue el auto1."<<endl;
            flag=false;
        }
    }
    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    Juego J;
    cout<<"Bienvenido al juego de autos. El auto que no choque gana."<<endl;
    J.play();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde está declarado el objeto `clase`?

Comment: Entonces deberia fijarme en las declaraciones? Disculpa que conteste de esta manera pero el codigo es muy largo para ponerlo aca (Por eso decidi solo poner la parte del problema)

Comment: Mira, esta bueno que aísles la parte que creas que causa el problema. Pasa que no lo puedo reproducir con el código que colocaste. Necesitamos suficiente codigo como para que podamos pegarlo en nuestro editor, compilarlo y ver el error. @Juan94

Comment: Pude agregar todo el codigo en esta ocasion. Gracias por el dato.

Comment: **Tampoco** es necesario que muestres **todo el codigo**. Debes consultar con urgencia lo que es un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora con mas codigo, si se puede identificar el error.

El error que me encuentro es que no defines `Auto1::Auto1(int, int, int)` ni `Auto::Auto(int)` ni otras mas. Por eso es que tienes el error del linker.

Por ejemplo con: `Auto1::Auto1(int, int, int)`, como el la linea 227 le dices a el compilador que la funcion existe, no te tira errores al compilar. Pero en el momento de hacer el link, no se puede encontrar la definicion de la funcion.

***Nota:*** La cantidad de codigo que compartiste es masivo. No esperes a que alguien se siente a leer 500 lineas de codigo para ver cual es el problema. El problema lo encontre entre los errores de linker y los avisos de intelisense. Si quieres que te ayudemos, tienes que reducir la cantidad de codigo que pones. O si quieres, trata de reproducir el problema con menos codigo. Por ejemplo aqui se pudo haber hecho asi:

```cpp
class A {
private:
    int val;
public:
    A();
};


int main(void) {
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

Y tenemos el problema mas claro. Aquí es obvio que no se definió `A::A()` y por eso tira errores el linker. Creeme que si tratas de aislar el problema de esa manera pasara una de 2 cosas:

1. Vas a ver el error de una forma mas clara, permitiéndote corregirlo de forma rápida
2. No vas a ver el error, de hecho, en la forma reducida funciona. Entonces te toca revisar la version completa para ver que no hisite.

Asi como recomendo @Trauma, tendrias que leer sobre como presentar un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)